# How to display unique links using GROUP_CONCAT clause

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, concatenation

I'm using the GROUP_CONCAT clause to group names of models that belong to a particular update. For example update A features model 1 and model 2. Each of the models has their own biography page. However, since I used the GROUP_CONCAT clause both the model 1 and model 2 links go to same biography page.
Instead of:

```
<a href="bio.php?model_id=1"> model 1 , model 2 </a>
```

I want this result:

```
<a href="bio.php?model_id=1"> model 1 </a> , <a href="bio.php?model_id=2"> model 2</a>
```

Here is SQL:

```
SELECT updates.update_id, title, posted, duration, updates.thumbnail, updates.alt_tag, updates.title_tag, updates.visible, models.model_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(' ', first_name, ' ', last_name, ' ')) AS full_name
FROM updates, models, updates_models
WHERE updates.update_id = updates_models.update_id AND models.model_id = updates_models.model_id
GROUP BY updates.update_id, title, posted, duration, updates.thumbnail, updates.alt_tag, updates.title_tag, updates.visible
```

Comment: You probably should not use `GROUP_CONCAT` or `GROUP BY` at all. Get everything and then loop through them and generate the links in PHP. Presentation or hypertext is not the responsibility of the database.

Comment: apokryfos - without GROUP_CONCAT I got back duplicate results.

Comment: If you don't get the correct results without grouping you're not fixing the problem if you group by but only sweeping it under the rug.

Comment: You can use `SELECT DISTINCT` to prevent duplicate rows.

Comment: apokryfos - do you have any suggestions as to achieve the desired result? When I use JOIN's I get duplicate thumbnails, title, dates, and so on. Instead of both models name being grouped under the same thumbnail, the same thumbnail is used twice with each model name under the same (but separate thumbnail.

Comment: Barmar - I have used SELECT DISTINCT, with or without it, the results are the same.  SELECT DISTINCT prevents separate rows, the rows aren't the same because each row has a different model name.